# Django default login view always populates the next field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I'm using the default django authentication system with little customization. The core functionality to login and logout is working as expected. The problem is with the following snippet in my login form template:

```
{% if next %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
{% endif %}
```

This is adapted from the example login view provided in the official documentation. The idea is that if the user tried to access a protected page without logging in, he/she would be redirected to the login page and the `next` parameter is set to the protected page's url. This is working fine.

However, when the user clicks on the login url and navigates directly to the login url, the above error message should not be displayed. But in this case, the `next` parameter is being set to the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` from `settings.py` and we see this error message.

I tried to debug to find where the problem is, and found it in `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` class. This class has a method `get_success_url` which gets the redirect url either from the `next` parameter or from the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. This method is being used to populate the context for the login form in the method `get_context_data`, which, in my opinion is incorrect. The `dispatch` method also uses the `get_success_url` to get the redirect url, which is correct because the purpose is to actually redirect.

I'm not sure if my explanation is clear, let me know if it isn't. Is there a workaround for this? Should I submit a bug report for this?

Using:

- Python: 3.6 (Anaconda3, 64 bit)
- Django: 1.11.1
- django-registration: 2.2

**Raised Django bug https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28229.**

Comment: can you post the error or stack trace and also the code for the settings and view file

Comment: There is no error stack trace. Please read the question text. The login view has the `next` property set when it shouldn't. That is the problem. There is no view either, I'm using the views the come with django's default auth system. And I haven't customized anything in the settings file beyond what's generated by `startproject`.

Comment: you said you  see error message? what is that?

Comment: The "error message" is what I wrote in the template, which is "Please login to see this page". It is displayed by the template because the `next` parameter is set, when it shouldn't be set.

Comment: are you using login_required decorator above the protected views? and do you have LOGIN_URL defined in the settings file?

Comment: Nope. I'm not using either of them. Just navigating to the login url in the browser by typing in the login url shows the "Please login to see this page" message, which it shouldn't.

Comment: class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

either you need to use login_required decorator for the view or use this class view

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem I'm complaining about. Please read the question text. The problem is not about accessing protected views. It is about navigating directly to the login page. When you go directly to the login page, you shouldn't see the "Please login to see this page" message.

Comment: yes because the problem is django is not getting the user session, try to {{ request.user.is_authenticated }} in the view, you will see blank

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion in my question is. Of course `is_authenticated` is blank, I'm trying to login by going to the login page. I don't expect to see `is_authenticated` to be true. I don't expect django to have a user session either because I haven't logged in yet. The problem is with the `next` parameter. Please post an answer if you believe this can solve my issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: bro i am telling even after login when you directly visit the protected page you will not find the user, as there is some problem with the login. whatever sorry for the long convo

Comment: Yes @Selcuk, that's a workaround. I intend to go with that if there's no solution. Thanks. Please post it as an answer so I can upvote/mark.

Comment: This seems like a regression in 1.11 due to the move to class-based authentication views. You can [open a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket) if you want.

Comment: Thanks @knbk. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but more like a workaround:

Assuming that your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is set to `/`, you could write `{% if next != "/" %}` instead of `{% if next %}`.